# How do I reorder Structure entries on the front-end?

Tags: entries, structure

I've have a page that has a drag and drop ability to reorder a group of Structure entries (using jquery).

I see order inside EntryModel (https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) but it looks like Structure positioning is handled outside the EntryModel.

Once dropped and and the entries are reordered it submits to an action inside a plugin. If I reorder two entries (or any number) how do I set the new structure order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place to do that sort of thing is [StructuresService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/StructuresService).

If we’re just talking about reordering a flat list of entries (no hierarchy), the only methods you need to worry about are [moveAfter()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/StructuresService#moveAfter-detail) (if an entry is being dragged after another one) and [prependToRoot()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/StructuresService#prependToRoot-detail) (if an entry is being dragged to the first position in the structure).

```php
$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById(1);
$prevEntry = craft()->entries->getEntryById(2);
$structureId = $entry->getSection()->structureId;

craft()->structures->moveAfter($structureId, $entry, $prevEntry);
```